# I need a JavaScript array to hold links to an image to work and be used in a image source

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I'm trying to make these images change. I need to store their links in an array but when I press the button to change the image, it doesn't recognise that the array variable links to an image. Can someone help please? Here is my current code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <script>

    var red = "https://s23.postimg.org/bo5a8hzsr/red_jpg.png"
    var yellow = "https://s23.postimg.org/bo5a8hzsr/red_jpg.png"
    var green = "https://s29.postimg.org/5ljr1ha3r/green.png"
    var lights=["red","yellow","green"]


    function changered()
    {
        var img = document.getElementById("light");
        img.src="lights[0]";
        return false;
    }

    function changeyellow()
    {
        var img = document.getElementById("light");
        img.src="lights[1]";
        return false;
    }

    function changegreen()
    {
        var img = document.getElementById("light");
        img.src="lights[2]";
        return false;
    }

  </script>

 </head>
 <body>
  <button id="red" onclick="setTimeout(changeyellow, 3000),setTimeout(changered, 6000),setTimeout(changegreen, 12000)">automatic</button>
  <button id="red" onclick="changered();">red</button>
  <button id="yellow" onclick="changeyellow();">yellow</button>
  <button id="green" onclick="changegreen();">green</button>
  <img id="light" src="https://s29.postimg.org/5ljr1ha3r/green.png" />
  <br><br><br>

 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: you're setting the src attribute to a string, you need to use just the array.

Comment: In other words `lights=[red,yellow,green]` and `img.src=lights[0];` etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case, you're setting the src attribute to the string "lights[0]" and not the value in the array at position 0.

Instead of this:

```
var img = document.getElementById("light");
        //vvvvvvvvv   
img.src="lights[0]";
return false;
```

You need to reference the values in your array. So it would become:

```
img.src = lights[0];
```

You'll need to do this in each of your function calls. Also you need to do the same thing with your array when you initialize it.

```
var lights = ["red","yellow","green"]
```

needs to become:

```
var lights = [red, yellow, green]
```

Comment: Thanks you where a massive help

Answer (score 1):

Your main problem here is that you are using the wrong variables, for example in the array, if you write:

```
lights = ["red","yellow","green"];
```

Your array values will be just static strings with the respective values `"red"`, `"yellow"` and `"green"`.

You need to change it to :

```
lights = [red,yellow,green];
```

So your array will hold the urls.

The same thing goes with the `src` as well, in your actual code:

```
img.src="lights[0]";
```

You are just setting a static string to the `src`. Change it to:

```
img.src= lights[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Please remove `""` from array element and `lights[0]`.
Here is the modified code:

```
var lights=[red,yellow,green];    

function changered()
{
    var img = document.getElementById("light");
    img.src=lights[0];
    return false;
}

function changeyellow()
{
    var img = document.getElementById("light");
    img.src=lights[1];
    return false;
}

function changegreen()
{
    var img = document.getElementById("light");
    img.src=lights[2];
    return false;
}
```